# Can we convert an image to Avro format in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, avro

Is it possible to convert an image into Avro format in Hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avro is used to describe a data schema which is platform independent manner (A 'data serialization system').

An image itself can be encoded in a variety of formats (PNG, JPEG, BMP, GIF etc), all of which can be represented as a sequence of bytes. You could additionally define some metadata about the image (which is probably encoded in the bytes anyway, but extracting it may be useful depending on your use case.

An primitive schema could be as follows (adapted from the [docs](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html#Defining+a+schema)):

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Image",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "filename", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "type",  "type": "string"},
     {"name": "data", "type": "bytes"},
     {"name": "width", "type": "int"},
     {"name": "height", "type": "int"}
 ]
}
```